getFeeForMessage returns null value
I am following docs and making the following solana rpc call to devnet solana(https://api.devnet.solana.com) but I am getting null value in response
this is my body
{
  "id":1,
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "method":"getFeeForMessage",
  "params":[
    "AQABAgIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEBAQAA"
  ]
}


You are using the default example transaction which probably uses an expired blockhash.
Using the latest blockhash should solve this,
Below is a snippet using umi when creating an account
async function getTransactionFee() {
    const newAccount = generateSigner(umi);
    const space = 42;

    const ixs = await createAccount(umi, {
        newAccount,
        payer: umi.payer,
        lamports: await umi.rpc.getRent(space),
        space,
        programId: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(SystemProgram.programId),
    })
        .getInstructions()
        .map((ix) => toWeb3JsInstruction(ix));

    const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
        payerKey: toWeb3JsPublicKey(umi.identity.publicKey),
        recentBlockhash: (await umi.rpc.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash,
        instructions: [...ixs],
    }).compileToV0Message([]);

    let b64EncodedMessage = Buffer.from(messageV0.serialize()).toString(
        "base64"
    );
    console.log("base64 encoded message ->", b64EncodedMessage);
    console.log();

    let x = await umi.rpc.call("getFeeForMessage", [b64EncodedMessage]);
    console.log(x);
}

getTransactionFee();

